# Pass button value to textarea value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, textarea

I'm attempting to send the value attached to my buttons to a textarea named "your-message" and require it to be by name using Javascript. However for some reason the value doesn't seem to pass properly to the text area.

Does anyone know where I may have gone wrong in my JavaScript?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function request_booking(objButton) {
        var booking = objButton.value;
        alert(booking);

        var textarea = document.getElementByName('your-message');
        textarea.value(booking);
    }
</script>

<button id="3" value="Start Date: 2016-02-12 \n Finish Date:  2017 -02-12 \n Additional Requests: \n" class="request-booking" onclick="request_booking(this)">Request</button>
<button onclick="request_booking(this)" class="request" id="2" value="2 Submitted" type="submit">Request</button>
<button onclick="request_booking(this)" class="request" id="3" value="3 Submitted" type="submit">Request</button>

<textarea aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" rows="10" cols="40" name="your-message"></textarea>
```

Comment: `$(textarea).val(booking); `?

Comment: I gave that a try and sadly no value passed when I attempted. I tried replacing "textarea.value(booking); with your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with some change

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
document.getElementsByName('your-message')[0].value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="3" value="Start Date: 2016-02-12 \n Finish Date:  2017 -02-12 \n Additional Requests: \n" class="request-booking" >Request</button>


<button  class="request" id="2" value="2 Submitted" type="submit">Request</button>


<button  class="request" id="3" value="3 Submitted" type="submit">Request</button>

<textarea name="your-message"></textarea>
```

There is a problem in function calling.Showing error that it doesnot found.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for however it uses the text area id="ta" is there a way to make it run using <textarea name="your-message"></textarea> ?   Would it be .getElementByName("your-message"); ?

Comment: Glad I could help you :) happie coding

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use  Element By Name Using Javascript

Then update your code

```
 var textarea = document.getElementByName('your-message');
textarea.value(booking);
```

with

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByName("your-message")[0];
textarea.value = booking;
```

[live demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/bCDiS6rscvP0c95X0S3g/)

Answer (score 1):

Assign value to `textarea` instead of passing, Also note you mis-spelled the function `getElementsByName`, s is missing in your call as you have `getElementByName`

*Change*

```
textarea.value(booking);
```

*To*

```
 textarea.value = booking;
```

You can even directly assign value.

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/guxepozoki/edit?html,js,output)

```
document.getElementsByName('your-message')[0].value = booking;
```

Comment: Would I use the same function as when I tried placing this code in replacement within the function I've setup it didn't work sadly. Very cool to see I can assign the value in one line though. Not sure why the function is causing issues.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Adil, I've marked the question solved with Debins solution. I appreciate your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var textarea = document.getElementByName('your-message');
textarea.value = booking;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion shu, I gave this a try and it didn't seem to work. Do you think it's due to my function or onclick setup?